# How nested for loops work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I need help understanding how to nest for loops in *C++* and how to understanding what is going on?

Can someone explain to me what is going on with these lines of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int MAX_ROWS = 3;
    const int MAX_COLS = 4;

    // 2D array of integers
    int MyInts[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {{34, -1, 879, 22},
                                      {24, 365, -101, -1},
                                      {-20, 40, 90, 97}};

    // iterate rows, each array of int
    for (int Row = 0; Row < MAX_ROWS; ++Row) {
        // iterate integers in each row (columns)
        for (int Column = 0; Column < MAX_COLS; ++Column) {
            cout << "Integer[" << Row << "][" << Column << "] = " << MyInts[Row][Column] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do I teach myself what that triple nested for loop is doing?

Comment: This code was from a book but i would like to know more about it

Comment: I advise you to go through some basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

> in what situation would you need it

generally you would require a nested for loop when

you have two (or more) dimensions to work with

```
   for e.g :  working with images, x and y dimensions

              working with matrix
```

> explanation of your code:

first you select a row to work with,

then in that selected row, you traverse all the columns

then you move on the second row

the outer loop takes care of moving to the second row, when all the columns of the first row have been processed/read

the inner for loop traverses the columns in the row selected by the outer loop

> logic behind it:

the outer loop waits for the inner loop to finish, then moves on to its own next iteration.

i.e. for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will cover its whole iterations.

as in your case, for every iteration of your outer loop 
the inner loop runs for 4 times (number of columns in each row)

and this process happens for all the rows, i.e. three times (number of rows)

Answer (score 1):

A nested loop through a 2D array means traversing each element belongs to a columns and repeat that for each row.

Explanation:

[image]

Comment: How did you produce or create that flowchart image

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's iterating a 2d array where it gives you the illusion of an actual table which consists of rows and columns. So first it's starts with the first row  where the index is 0 and goes to the second for loop(column) and iterates round it till it reaches the max column and goes back up to the first for loop and goes to the next row (index) and so on until it reaches the max row then it stops . Hope this helped a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Any book on C++, will have a chapter on looping.

When you **"nest"** two loops, the outer loop takes control of the number of complete repetitions of the inner loop.  While all types of loops may be nested, the most commonly nested loops are `for` loops.

When you are dealing with **2 - d array**, That is, which consists of both **row and column**, the nested for loop can be used.

Example: You have two dimensional array of three rows and four columns and what you need to do is to individually access each element in an array one element per line.

As in your code you have two loops, where first loop is iterating through rows and what your second loop is doing is that its iterating through columns.

Here, the variable **Row** in outer loop is initialized to zero

`Row = 0`, this is your 0th row, then the loop goes into inner loop where the loop is run from `Column=0` until the condition `Column < MAX_COLS` is reached -

`Column = 0;` will `cout` i.e. print `Integer[0][0]=34`

Then, `Column` is incremented(`++Column`) and checked that if it is less than `MAX_COLS`(`Column < MAX_COLS;`) 
If yes then it prints `Integer[` **the row number in which it is on**`][`**the column number in which it is on**`]` `=` **value at that place**

This is done until `MAX_COLS` thus displaying **4** columns. Then loop moves to the outer loop again, increments row(`++Row`) checks if the value is less than `MAX_ROWS;` and the process continues until `MAX_ROWS`=3. Then Stops.

Try this same example with different values for row and column and run your program in debug. You will understand what is going on exactly.

The output you get is:

```
Integer[0][0] = 34
Integer[0][1] = -1
Integer[0][2] = 879
Integer[0][3] = 22
Integer[1][0] = 24
Integer[1][1] = 365
Integer[1][2] = -101
Integer[1][3] = -1
Integer[2][0] = -20
Integer[2][1] = 40    
Integer[2][2] = 90
Integer[2][3] = 97
```

I really hope you will get something from this.